# performance issue of recv in c

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I have implement socket communication like the following :

The socket Client send "0010ABCDEFGHIJ"  to the socket server ,
the first 4 bytes(in this case , "0010") describe the message body has 10 bytes,
and those bytes followed are message body !!

I use "The Linux Programming Interface" readn function in server side , 
the source :

```
ssize_t
readnx(int fd, void *buffer, size_t n)
{
    ssize_t numRead;                    /* # of bytes fetched by last read() */
    size_t totRead;                     /* Total # of bytes read so far */
    char *buf;

    buf = (char*) buffer;               /* No pointer arithmetic on "void *" */
    for (totRead = 0; totRead < n; ) {
        numRead = recv(fd, buf, n - totRead,MSG_NOSIGNAL);

        if (numRead == 0)               /* EOF */
            return totRead;             /* May be 0 if this is first read() */
        if (numRead == -1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;               /* Interrupted --> restart read() */
            else
                return -1;              /* Some other error */
        }
        totRead += numRead;
        buf += numRead;
    }
    return totRead;                     /* Must be 'n' bytes if we get here */
}


void *thread1(void *param)
{
    int nread = 0  ;
    char strdata[1024]={0},strtmp[128]={0} ;
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    while(1)
    {
        memset(strtmp,0x00,sizeof(strtmp)) ;
        if ( (nread = readnx(sd,strtmp,4)) <=  0){
            break ;
        }
        int ilen = atoi(strtmp) ;
        memset( strdata,0x00,sizeof(strdata) ) ;
        if ( (nread = readnx(sd,strdata,ilen)) <= 0){
            break ;
        }
    }//while
}
```

This works fine to me  , I like to know more details about performance ,
I have 2 readnx function calls in my source code , and  doing it in 
blocking mode , If I change my code to make recv with MSG_PEEK first ,
once all 14 bytes are all available , then call readnx once to fetch all datas,
Would it be faster than my original 2 readnx calls ?!

I am wondering in my original source , I have 2 readnx to recv "0010" 
and "ABCDEFGHIJ" separately , Would this cause linux kernel to copy to 
user space twice even all 14 bytes are all there already at the time I 
called first readnx ?!   Or  the kernel copy all 14 bytes to user space 
just once , the readnx function just read it from user space ?!

If I like to know those details about kernel to user space procedures ,
what documents,function call could help me to go through the details.

Comment: remove C++ tag now ..sorry for mistake .

Comment: Btw since you're interested in reducing overhead, you may want to get rid of those memset() calls -- since recv() is going to immediately overwrite those same bytes anyway.  No sense in overwriting them twice.  (You will need to write a single NUL terminator byte at the nread'th position to make the string NUL-terminated so that atoi() will work correctly, though)

Comment: The number of recv() calls per message could be reduced to 1 (or less) by always reading in as many bytes as possible on each call (into a large array), and then parsing as many bytes as possible out of that array and keeping the rest around for later.  The downside is that the state-logic required to do it that way is quite a bit more complicated and tricky to get right in all cases, and I'd be surprised if you'd see any measurable difference in performance unless your incoming data stream is extremely fast (e.g. hundreds-of-megabytes-per-second) or your CPU is really slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I change my code to make recv with MSG_PEEK first, once all 14 bytes are all available

That implies that you're going to sleep and retry. How long are you going to sleep for? How do you know how far apart in time the pieces are going to arrive?

> then call readnx once to fetch all datas, Would it be faster than my original 2 readnx calls?

No. You won't sleep for the correct amount of time, unlike `recv()`, and you might do a lot more than one MSG_PEEK receives.

If you're concerned about the performance of the two `recv()` calls, or however many it takes, you should do your best at the *sender* to ensure the header and the message are sent at the same time: have a look at `sendmsg()`.